# Removing network adapters in Windows

Tags: windows, networking, adapter

What is the difference between WiMax 6150 and Wireless-N 6150 ?

Also I would like to remove some of the network adapters, how ?

[image: network adapters image link]

Comment: The 6150 note it says "network cable unplugged" whereas the N-6150 is your wireless.  I let someone else address the miniport adapters tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

N-6150 is the wireless Ethernet adapter and wimax 6150 is the wired ethernet adapter.. its not necessary to remove them, they will cause no harm to you, if require. right click> Disable or else , you can go device management Window[Right Click My Computer>Manage>Device Management] , Click Network Adapters , Right click the adapter you want to uninstall , Click Ok.. That's it..

Comment: how about the Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter? and thank you for the answer :)

Comment: Those adapters are used by Microsoft Virtual Wifi, which allows you to connect your laptop to a wired or wireless network, and make your laptop an access point for other devices (mobile, tablet...) so they can use that connection too, if they don't support wired connections, or if you use a hotspot that restricts you to a single device etc... Googling Microsoft Virtual Wifi will give you a lot more explanation. However, after having to experience it the painful way, I would advise you not to delete, but disable them. Deleting them might make Windows behave... strange sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

All those are there because the hardware is present and "discovered" by your Windows. You don't want to "remove" it from there; if it bugs you that it might interfere with something, just "disable" it.

While this doesn't address removal outright, it does address an implied concern which is "too many active network adapters".

Comment: This does not seem to add to the accepted answer

Comment: I disagree, Dave. I answered the person who wanted to remove something that they'd better not to remove those items. IMHO it is pretty much all the answer needed there.

Comment: This is really more of an opinion or helpful advice than a solution to what was asked in the question.  With the site's Q&A format, answers are reserved for solutions to what was asked.  This would be more appropriate as a comment, which requires a little more rep.

Comment: Alright, I got your point. Thanks for the input guys, will keep those as SU-guidelines in my mind ;-)